# What is this surface $x^2 + y^2 +2z = 2, z \geq 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a surface $x^2 + y^2 +2z = 2, z \geq 0$.

I see that $x^2 + y^2 +2z = 2$  is a paraboloid with vertex at  $z=1$ opening downwards and also it is above XY plane. My doubt is that whether the surface includes closed disc $(x^2 + y^2 = 2)$ in xy plane or not?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. To take $x,y$ cross-sections simply substitute in the value of $z$. For example, the intersection with the $x,y$ plane is given by setting $z = 0$, i.e. the solution set of $x^2 + y^2 = 2$.

Comment: If you mean to say circle $x^2+y^2=2$, then yes. However, if you mean disc $x^2+y^2\leq 2$, then no.This is because when $xy$ plane cuts the surface, it gives a curve, which is  a circle in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how it look like. The section above z plan (z>0) applies,

[image]